# Set Stack Overflows's login website focus to the login textboxes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, login

I know this is quite a little thing and not a huge deal, but why cant we set the focus of the cursor upon loading the [Stack Overflow login website](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F) to the `email textBox`? This is quite a common thing upon popular websites that the focus is automatically set to the login textBoxes at the login form.

Personally I think that this procedure is just way more comfortable for users to login. Just loading the website, (now no required mouse movement) fill in one textBox, *`tab`* and fill in the other one. As I said its not quite a big deal, but since the associated work for this is really small I consider this as making Stack Overflow easily a bit more convenient.

So, what do you think about that?

Comment: @Stijn How is this a duplicate if there isnt an answer? I am asking *you guys* what do you think about it. If it gets enough attention the web developers might stumble upon this one day...

Comment: On meta it isn't required to have a duplicate with an answer. The question there seems to apply and has plenty of comments. Add your concerns and support to get it fixed there. It is best to focus the attention, not scatter it across multiple posts.

Comment: IIRC correctly, SE do get a lot of failed login attempts from users who enter their facebook or gmail credentials in those textboxes. Setting the focus on them might increase that number but it would need A/B testing to verify.

Comment: @rene I understand that behaviour and it makes sense to focus the attention. But this post is 2 years old, barely got attention and a newer asked question (like mine) could gather some more attention since its asked *now* and is not buried unter thousands of over posts, right? But wont be possible with an instant duplicapte flag.

Comment: @rene But setting a focus to a texBox wouldnt increase this number, since the only thing that happens is saving the required mouse movement.

Comment: Just give it [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) ...

Comment: It does increase the number because those users that start to type now find themselves focused on a button that doesn't take their typing ...

Comment: @rene Ahaha ok I give it 6 to 8. But just leaving this question here or adresssing this desire to an Stack Overflow Valued Associate?

Comment: @rene But those do need to use their mouse anyway so it doesnt make a change for them at all. But for those like me it it does have a positive effect. I think users that login with gmail or facebook are quite a minority or arent they?

Comment: In 2015 a member of staff claimed that Google was the most identity provider but I try to get some recent numbers

Comment: The numbers aren't readily available so we have to do it with the expectation of [Jon, that Google is still the most used identity provider](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6513724#6513724)

Comment: Wow ok, I am quite surprised not to say shocked. Thank you for the information, but I dont get it why someone would ever use Google for that, I think SE OpenID is quite useful. But i wonder that there arent any public availabel numbers about which user use which way to log in. Could probably be an easy query for some staff of SO.

Comment: If they do not have it in their database they use for running data analysis on, they would have to query on production which I doubt they will do for this.

Comment: @rene Yes I doubt that now too, unfortenately. It would be quite interesting to know though. Back to my *desire*, shell i contact some SO staff or just wait for a mircale to take place?

Comment: What do you want them to contact for? To get the number or to get the focus fixed?

Comment: @rene I´d like both. But to be realistic and more important is to get the focus fixed.

Comment: For the numbers you could start a new meta post, for the feature request to be implemented: I wouldn't bother them, you did what you're supposed to do, they are prioritizing as they see fit, only marginally influenced by what happens on meta. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662

Comment: @rene Ok, thank you for your advice. Will do so. Was nice having a talk. :-)

Comment: It's quite funny since it's marked as a dup and got at first -2 votes, but apparently I am not the only one that wishes that *feature* since it got +2 votes now.